# Datasheet electrical characteristics parameters confusion

Tags: analog, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, datasheet, dac

I'm reading the datasheet of [DAC8512](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/DAC8512.pdf). What I can't understand is about some pulse widths, the indicated minimum value is larger than the typical value.  Is this the datasheet mistake or I misunderstand something?
[image]

Comment: Ah let me try my broken English. (1) Suppose every morning you collect a basket of eggs in the forest, from a big varieties of birds. (2) Now suppose you know from past experience that even the eggs that need longest boiling time need at most 30 minutes. In other words you guarantee that 30 minutes is the guaranteed minimum time for any egg. (3)  But you do know that most of the eggs need 5 to 15 minutes, and the average is around 10 minutes. So your egg spec is 30 minutes min, 10 minutes typical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See note 4, "These parameters are **guaranteed by design** and not subject to production testing" -- unlike the other parameters where a production test program makes a measurement and bins any devices that fail the min/max limits, a Guaranteed By Design parameter is accomplished as part of the logic timing simulation. I don't have any insight particular to Analog Devices, but generally in the industry, production wafers usually include a few test coupon sites that are used for process control. As long as the wafer meets the production design requirements (gate oxide capacitance, sheet resistance, etc.), then the logic timing is guaranteed to meet the specification.

What they're trying to show with this table is that for example the Data Hold time requires 15ns under all worst-case manufacturing variances, so that's what they claim as their "min" limit, but presumably an applications engineer tested a sample of real devices and found that on the ones they looked at in their lab, typically they only need 5ns; the typical/min numbers give you and idea of how much guardband there is.

If you design your system to run at a clock frequency of 1/(30ns+30ns) then it will definitely work, and if you design for a clock frequency of 1/(10ns+10ns) it will *typically* work.

For a high volume production line meant to serve for many years, ignore the typical values and stick with the guaranteed limits. But if you're only building a few units, and you want to trade off higher performance for reliability, the typical value gives you some guidance what you can expect.

Note that it might not always work, it might need more over temperature, and in the long term some batches of parts might come out with a different typical value. As long as those parts still meet the min/max specs they're technically not failed parts, the typical specs are not guaranteed. That's the hazard of designing with typical specs rather than worst-case sepcs.

Answer (score 0):

Your misunderstanding is that these are inputs, not outputs.

Inputs that make a transition from one state to the other and then back again have to be long enough that they are recognised by the chip. If the input buffer has different delays for high going and low going edges (which it will have, they are never identical), then it will suffer pulse width distortion, and some very narrow pulses will simply not cause the internal gates to change state at all.

The minimum spec is saying that all devices, under worst case voltage, temperature and manufacturing variations, will respond properly to a 30 nS pulse. However, most chips will typically respond to a 20 or even 10 nS pulse.

The difference between minimums and typical might be useful if you are prepared to test each product for speed, and perhaps sell the 'fast' ones at a premium, and sell those that only work at 30 nS more cheaply. Otherwise, just design to the minimums to make sure they will work.